# When I react-native run-ios bundle not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react-native project When I start `react-native run-android` on windows 10 environment it's working but I worked `react-native run-ios` MacOS environment my bundle terminal gives this error,

```
    Loading dependency graph...(node:46534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
 Duplicate module name: react-native
 Paths: /Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/ios/Pods/React/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
   at setModule (/Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
   at workerReply (/Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
(node:46534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:46534) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:46534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
 Duplicate module name: react-native
 Paths: /Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/ios/Pods/React/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
   at setModule (/Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
   at workerReply (/Users/tanfener/Desktop/MPP/mpp/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
(node:46534) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

I tried

- delete all node_modules
- clear npm cache
- delete watchman
- I create new project its work but it's not working on my project 
  my package.json like that 
  https://ybin.me/p/8941c752fb540ea5#AxqA/1Ckte5N2k8crVggkmQGiRQjP5VOAF/TIxRo4Dw=

Podfile

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'mpp' do
 # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
 # use_frameworks!
 pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
 pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'

 # Pods for mpp

 target 'mppTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue and below command help to solve it.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install
npm cache clean
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: I didn't add any libs I just pushed windows, run pull then run-ios from macos

Comment: I  init a new project and adaptation my codes it's work. Old has problem project when i pod install then i took this error

Comment: I added to my question @Nirmalsinh